# Change SyncAdapter in my app for another solution to sync

Tags: java, android, android-syncadapter

I already have my app in production, but I want to remove the sync adapter function without affecting the app's functionality. is there any approach in which I don't make a mess with my app?

I need to solve this because sometimes the app stay in *syncPending* and the users can't use it for long time.

I read about JobService but I don't know if I have to do a big change to implement it.

Comment: Maybe you just need to resolve the issues that make the app unusable instead of refactoring SyncAdapter out? I personally used SyncAdapters on several apps and never had such issues.

Comment: Thank you for answering, can u recommend me any good code practices or documentation about sync adapters?

Comment: Unfortunately, SynAdapter is one of the least documented Android frameworks. This blog helped me a great deal: http://blog.udinic.com/2013/07/24/write-your-own-android-sync-adapter/